# Regex to remove footer using wildcards

Tags: regex

Ok - this is well beyond my limited knowledge of regular expressions.  We receive a report from a banking entity in a fixed with text file format.  Unfortunately their system exports page headers with the data file that must be removed before processing on our end.  The page headers start and end with the same text but the content changes (dates and page numbers).  A typical one looks like:

```
00007xxxxx     LAST1,FIRST1            111111       20120930
ABCD                    EXPORT RPT          10/04/12 at 10/04/12 16:20   Seq 1501   Page    16

MRK014 Report Date: 10/04/12

Acct#          Name                   SH. Balance       QTR (YYYYMMDD)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00007xxxxx     LAST2,FIRST2            222222       20120930
```

So each header starts with "ABCD" (actually the name of the bank, just removed here for privacy) and ends with the row of -------------------.

What I need to get it down to is the customer data on two rows (00007xxxxx - those account numbers change per person).

So I need to select from the " ABCD" to the end of the "---" to remove that block of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex.. This is a Java code.. You can use the given pattern in your language..

```
str = str.replaceAll("ABCD((.*?)[\n\r])+(\\-*)", "");
```

Where `str` contains your above data.. Lines are separated by `\n` I assume..

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you are removing correct part of report I would go with more complicated regex pattern.

Use regex pattern

```
(?<=[\n\r])ABCD\s+EXPORT\s+RPT\s[^-]+[\n\r]\-+[\n\r]+
```

and replace each match with empty string.

However if your environment does not support regex lookbehind, then you have to use pattern:

```
([\n\r])ABCD\s+EXPORT\s+RPT\s[^-]+[\n\r]\-+[\n\r]+
```

and replace each match with first group.

For example in ***JavaScript*** it would be:

```
str.replace(/([\n\r])ABCD\s+EXPORT\s+RPT\s[^-]+[\n\r]\-+[\n\r]+/g, "$1")
```

Test this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfWDW/).